# how to sort a string list with integer and no separator

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort this list. My files looks like this : "crown"+"t"+"0.01"
I would like to sort this list in function of t with t increasing.
Thanks you.

```
import glob

txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob("crown*0.01"):
    txtfiles.append(file)
print(txtfiles)
```

output :

```
['crown0.90.01', 'crown0.250.01', 'crown0.550.01', 'crown0.650.01', 'crown1.90.01', 'crown2.10.01', 'crown0.850.01', 'crown0.20.01', 'crown0.80.01', 'crown0.10.01']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort()` function will work. You can try this:-

```
l = ['crown0.90.01', 'crown0.250.01', 'crown0.550.01', 'crown0.650.01', 'crown1.90.01', 'crown2.10.01', 'crown0.850.01', 'crown0.20.01', 'crown0.80.01', 'crown0.10.01']
l.sort()
print(l)
```

Output:-

```
['crown0.10.01', 'crown0.20.01', 'crown0.250.01', 'crown0.550.01', 'crown0.650.01', 'crown0.80.01', 'crown0.850.01', 'crown0.90.01', 'crown1.90.01', 'crown2.10.01']
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think this function was capable of doing that...